# Maintain Firebase Authentication state after exiting app on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the following class to handle the authentication state and login for users:

```
class AuthenticationState: NSObject, ObservableObject {

     // MARK: Properties
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var loggedInUser: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var isAuthenticating = false
    @Published var error: NSError?

    static let shared = AuthenticationState()

    private let authState = Auth.auth()
    fileprivate var currentNonce: String?

    // MARK: Methods
    func login(with loginOption: LoginOption) {
        self.isAuthenticating = true
        self.error = nil

        switch loginOption {
            case .signInWithApple:
                handleSignInWithApple()

            case let .emailAndPassword(email, password):
                handleSignInWith(email: email, password: password)
        }
    }

    private func handleSignInWith(email: String, password: String) {
        authState.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handleAuthResultCompletion)
    }

    func signup(email: String, password: String, passwordConfirmation: String) {
        guard password == passwordConfirmation else {
            self.error = NSError(domain: "", code: 9210, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Password and confirmation does not match"])
            return
        }

        self.isAuthenticating = true
        self.error = nil

        authState.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handleAuthResultCompletion)
    }

    private func handleAuthResultCompletion(auth: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.isAuthenticating = false
            if let user = auth?.user {
                self.loggedInUser = user
            } else if let error = error {
                self.error = error as NSError
            }
        }
    }

    func signout() {
        try? authState.signOut()
        self.loggedInUser = nil
    }
}

// Extension Below that handles sign in with apple, etc.
```

This works great for handling a variety of sign in methods, however when the user exits the app, the logged in state no longer persists. What would be the best way to keep the user logged in after exiting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do what you wanna do. Save your data, any kind of data - it's up to you in your local storage, such as:

1. Defaults
2. Keychain
3. Core Data
4. and whatnot....

Alternatively, in my opinion, you could just try to check the `currentUser`, like so:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
```

doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

and for javascript: (Authentication State Persistence
) https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: checking `Auth.auth().currentUser` worked perfectly. I added a function to set my logged in user to `Auth.auth().currentUser` if there is one saved, otherwise it defaults to the login screen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication automatically persists the user's authentication state to their keychain, and tries to restore that state when the app is restarted.

To restore the authentication state, it needs to recheck the credentials with the server, which may take some time. That's why you need to use an auth state listener to pick up this restored state, as shown in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Ok so I understand that I need to add a listener, I'm just not quite sure where to implement it. Do I include that as a method in the AuthenticationState class?